# How to setup Kerberos in a Linux server and Connect it to AD for Authentication

Tags: kerberos

I have an Active Directory in a server and I have been allocated another Linux server for Kerberos. Can you send me the steps for Installing the Kerberos in the Linux machine and connect it with AD for Authentication?

Comment: You did not tell which Linux distribution you are using, so https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system-level_authentication_guide/configuring_a_kerberos_5_client tells how to configure Kerberos Client for REHL7

Comment: Hard to guess what you mean. If you want to get manually a Kerberos ticket from inside a Linux session, after looging with a local Linux account, then look at the link above. If you want to avoid local Linux user accounts and use AD accounts on Linux, then look into SSSD https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system-level_authentication_guide/sssd >> good luck _(evil laugh fading in the distance)_

Comment: Thanks for the advise .  I am using Linux RHEL 7.2 and i will be installing the KDC on this machine. My requirement is , my applications (Cloudera & Vertica) should be authenticated using Kerberos. When a user tries to connect to these applications, the request should go to KDC in the linux machine and the KDC Should verify the credentials in AD. I would need advise on how to install KDC in Linux Machine and how to make the user credentials get verified against AD. I am checking the Links that you have provided.